# Mapping through an Array with .map() but excluding 1 item

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map, capitalize

I have an array:

```
let people = ['lucy', 'jerry', 'ricky', 'jessy', 'jerry', 'phil']
```

And I want to capitalize every word except jerry. How would I go about this?

I know how to map through the array:

```
let output = people.map(person => { 
      return person.toUpperCase()
}
console.log(output)
```

Obviously, that returns the entire array with every word capitalized.
But again, what if I wanted to capitalize all of the words in the array except jerry, which is written twice?

Comment: Use an if statement

Comment: So the criteria is known then? "jerry" will be untouched? Or, is the criteria any random name that shows up more than once?

Comment: I'm just trying to capitalize all of the other names in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and scalable method. Set the exclusions in their own array and just check for them in the map loop.

```js
let people = ['lucy', 'jerry', 'ricky', 'jessy', 'jerry', 'phil']
let exclude=['jerry'];

let output = people.map(person => exclude.includes(person) ? person : person.toUpperCase())
console.log(output)


let output2 = people.map(person => exclude.includes(person) ? person : person[0].toUpperCase() + person.slice(1))
console.log(output2)
```